# R Programming - Parallel Processing of Loops

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I have a data set with around 1000 columns/parameters and want to perform regression among each of these parameters. So, data in column 1 will be stacked against all other 999 parameters for linear regression and so on.

The nonoptimized version of this approach would be:

```
loop <- c(1:ncol(Data))
for ( column in loop ){

    # Fetch next data to be compared
    nextColumn <- column + 1

    # Fetch next column
    while ( nextColumn <= ncol(Data) ){   

       # Analysis logic

       # Increment the counter
       nextColumn <- nextColumn + 1

   }
}
```

Above code will work, but will take lot of time. To optimize, I want to use parallel processing in R. There are many different packages which can be useful in this case, for example `parallel` and `doparallel` as [explained in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38318139/run-a-for-loop-in-parallel-in-r).

However, there might be some overhead involved which as a new R programmer I might not be aware off. I am looking for suggestions from R experts on better way to write above code in R and whether any specific package can be useful.

Looking forward to suggestions, thanks.

Comment: If you are new to R, I wouldn't try to parallelize your code. Call your regression function inside apply(). Have a look at the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20342661/apply-in-r-with-user-defined-function).

Comment: @JamieMac: Thanks. I am having hard time figuring out how `apply()` will fetch two columns/parameters at a time, perform regression and moves to next combination. Currently, in the analysis logic I am also capturing all the `summary()` data, so I have a vector that keeps updating while regression loops through different columns/parameters. Still reading through `apply()` documents, but if you have any suggestions, please do share.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `mapply` like this:

```
X <- 1:(ncol(mtcars)-1)     # first through penultimate column
Y <- 2:ncol(mtcars)         # second through last column
mapply(function(x,y) sum(mtcars[,x],mtcars[,y]), X, Y)
```